# Reactive Inputs using modules in ShinyDashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to use reactive selectizeInput by first time in shiny modules, but It's not working. I read the documentation of modules and reactive inputs, but I don't know how to work with it together. I made a simplify code to show my doubt. This is the code without modules, It's working well:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)

a<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<- c(0.5,1,2,6,8)

dt <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-05"), by = "days")
ts <- xts(a, dt )
names(ts)="a"
ts$b <- xts(b, dt )
ui<-dashboardPage(title= "Dashboard", skin= "green",
                  dashboardHeader(title="PROYECTO"),
                  dashboardSidebar(
                    sidebarMenu(id="sidebarID",
                                menuItem("OVERVIEW",tabName = "datos"
                                )                                
                    )                   
                    
                  ),
                  dashboardBody(
                    
                    tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "datos", 
                                     fluidRow(
                                       column(width = 6,
                                              selectizeInput("select",
                                                             "Choose",
                                                             c("a"="1",
                                                               "b"="2")
                                              )),
                                       box(width=6, column( width=12,
                                                                   
                                                                   column(width=12,highchartOutput("y"))
                                     ),
                                     height = 400))                                                    
                                     
                    )
                    )))

server <- function(input, output,session) { 
  
  
  y_react<-reactive(
    highchart(type="stock") %>%
      hc_add_series(ts[,as.numeric(input$select)],
                    type = "line",
                    color="red")
  )
  output$y <-renderHighchart(y_react())
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, I was trying to adapt it into modules. I created a module:

```
a<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<- c(0.5,1,2,6,8)

dt <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-05"), by = "days")
ts <- xts(a, dt )
names(ts)="a"
ts$b <- xts(b, dt )


yUI<-function(id) {tagList(highchartOutput(NS(id,"y")))
}

yServer<-function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    y_react<-reactive(
      highchart(type="stock") %>%
        hc_add_series(ts[,as.numeric(input$select)],
                      type = "line",
                      color="red")
    )
    
    output$y <-renderHighchart(y_react())
    
    
  })}
```

And shiny dashboard:

```
a<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<- c(0.5,1,2,6,8)

dt <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-05"), by = "days")
ts <- xts(a, dt )
names(ts)="a"
ts$b <- xts(b, dt )


yUI<-function(id) {tagList(highchartOutput(NS(id,"y")))
}

yServer<-function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    y_react<-reactive(
      highchart(type="stock") %>%
        hc_add_series(ts[,as.numeric(input$select)],
                      type = "line",
                      color="red")
    )
    
    output$y <-renderHighchart(y_react())
    
    
  })}
```

But It's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the module server you are using `input$select` which however is created outside of the module. Doing so the server will look for a `select` in the module namespace. However, as there is no input with ID `select` in the module namespace you get an error.

To fix that you could pass the `input$select` to the module server as an argument:

````
``` r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)
library(xts)

yUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    highchartOutput(NS(id, "y"))
  )
}

yServer <- function(id, choice) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    y_react <- reactive(
      highchart(type = "stock") %>%
        hc_add_series(ts[, choice],
          type = "line",
          color = "red"
        )
    )
    output$y <- renderHighchart(y_react())
  })
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "Dashboard", skin = "green",
  dashboardHeader(title = "PROYECTO"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebarID",
      menuItem("OVERVIEW", tabName = "datos")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(tabItem(
      tabName = "datos",
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          selectizeInput(
            "select",
            "Choose",
            c(
              "a" = "1",
              "b" = "2"
            )
          )
        ),
        box(
          width = 6, column(
            width = 12,
            column(width = 12, yUI("y"))
          ),
          height = 400
        )
      )
    ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  yServer("y", as.numeric(input$select))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3301
````

[image]

A second option and probably more in the spirt of what modules are meant for would be to include the `selectizeInput` in the module. Doing so the input with inputID `select` becomes part of the module namespace and can be accessed from within the module server using `input$select`. As you want to place the UI elements in different parts of your dashboard I decided for two module UI "functions" which adds the flexibility to place the UI elements individually:

```r
yUI_plot <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    highchartOutput(NS(id, "y"))
  )
}

yUI_select <- function(id) {
  selectizeInput(
    NS(id, "select"),
    "Choose",
    c(
      "a" = "1",
      "b" = "2"
    )
  )
}

yServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    y_react <- reactive(
      highchart(type = "stock") %>%
        hc_add_series(ts[, as.numeric(input$select)],
                      type = "line",
                      color = "red"
        )
    )
    output$y <- renderHighchart(y_react())
  })
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "Dashboard", skin = "green",
  dashboardHeader(title = "PROYECTO"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebarID",
      menuItem("OVERVIEW", tabName = "datos")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(tabItem(
      tabName = "datos",
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          yUI_select("y")
        ),
        box(
          width = 6, column(
            width = 12,
            column(width = 12, yUI_plot("y"))
          ),
          height = 400
        )
      )
    ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  yServer("y")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7210
```

[image]